# Cointegration and Granger causality

Tags: time-series, cointegration, granger-causality

Can anyone please tell me whether the existence of cointegration between two series necessarily implies Granger causality between their "first differences"? I'd appreciate it if you could explain your reason.

Comment: yes. granger causality says that, if including X in a model, improves ones prediction of Y, then X granger causes Y. In the case of cointegration, the ECM formulation shows explicitly that knowing $(X_t - X_{t-1})$ improves the prediction of $(Y_t - Y_{t-1})$ which are both first differences.

Comment: @mlofton, it is always good to emphasize that Granger causality deals with incremental improvement in prediction accuracy once lags of $Y$ have been conditioned on. I have seen too many instances where people forget that and then incorrectly conclude that e.g. early-morning bird songs Granger-cause sunrise...

Comment: @Richard Hardy: Yes, I hope that I said that sort of but probably did  not give it  enough emphasis. The interesting thing about cointegration ( atleast in the engle-granger case where there are just two variables ) is that, as the OP said, the first difference of $X_t$ granger causes the first difference of $Y_t$. I never thought of it that way until I read the question.

Comment: Does this vary with the type of cointegration used? For example I am learning it in the context of the ARDL bounds test. Not the Engel Granger method (and still understand the concept very generally at best). I know these two approaches are quite different.

Comment: A quotation from Dave Giles blog: ["If two or more time-series are cointegrated, then there must be Granger causality between them - either one-way or in both directions. However, the converse is not true."](https://davegiles.blogspot.com/2011/04/testing-for-granger-causality.html). The blog post is very well written – go ahead and read it. Perhaps you will find the answer to your question as well.

Comment: @mlofton Can you elaborate? I am puzzled:

Take $X_t = t + e_t$ and $Y_t = -X_t = -t - e_t$. I would say X and Y are cointegrated (as $X+Y=0$) but neither Granger causes the other, as lagged values of one does not improve prediction of the other.

Comment: @bixiou, they cannot be cointegrated without being integrated. And they are not integrated...

Comment: Why are they not integrated? Isn't a process with a linear trend integrated of order 1?

Comment: @bixiou, of course not. Have you checked the definition of an integrated process?

Comment: @Bixiou: A process that is integrated of order $d$ is, by definition, stationary when differenced  $d$ times. But you have a made a deterministic function of $Y_t$ by making it a linear function of  $X_t$. Note that  one can't say that the $X_t$ process is integrated because, differencing, $X_t$, you get $X_{t} - X_{t-1} = 1 + \epsilon_t - \epsilon_{t-1}$. At time $t, \epsilon_{t-1}$ is known and probably not zero and is changing at each time $t$. So, one would not define $X_t$ as a being an I(1) process. It's a trend stationary process but, AFAIK, still not defined as being integrated.

Comment: @bixiou: Thinking about this some more ( note that I'm not familiar with the exact definition of "integrated" ) maybe, technically speaking, the  process you describe could be termed "integrated". But, referrring back to your point that neither Granger causes the other. I'm not so sure about that. If one knows lagged values of $X_t$, it seems to me like that would improve the prediction of $Y_t$. It's an interesting question ( whose answer is currently escaping me )  but your creating a deterministic series which won't exist in practice.

Comment: @mlofton, for the presence of Granger causality, you need lagged values of $X_t$ to contribute to prediction beyond the contribution of the lagged values of $Y_t$. This is not the case, so there is no Granger causality there. bixiou, this also addresses the same nuance that is missing in one of your earlier comments.

Comment: Hi Richard: I understand what you are saying which is good point. But, in bixiou's contrived example, knowing lagged values of $Y_t$ is the same as knowing lagged values of $X_t$ because they are functionally related ( even have the same error term ). So, lagged values of $Y_t = -1.0  \times $  lagged values of $X_t$ for all $t$.

Comment: Basically what I'm saying is how does one define granger causality when lagged values of one variable are functionally related to lagged values of the other variable. Maybe a different error term on -X_t would make more sense. This way they wouldn't be functionally related atleast.

Comment: @mlofton, I do not see why we cannot use the standard definition. And the implication of that is clear: X does not Granger-cause Y.

Comment: I think that you are correct. For his example, given lags of $Y$, $X$ won't help. But it's definitely a weird example because there's n exact deterministic relationship between $X_t$ and $Y_t$.  What I was referring  was that this "determinism" would atleast go away a little if you had a different error term on $X_{t}$. But yes, for the example, I would say that neither variable granger causes the other. Apologies for noise.

Comment: @mlofton, thank you for an interesting discussion!

Comment: same here. the cointegration concept is interesting theoretically. but practically and implementation wise, difficult to deal with.